# "In order to" + "there is/are"

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it correct to fuse and use "in order to" + "there is" in this way:

> Could you send me the documents before the end of September **in order
>   there to be** enough time to ensure...

, please?

Comment: I believe this is just missing a word" Could you send me the documents before the end of September in order **for** there to be enough time to ensure..."

Comment: **...September to allow enough time...** would be a less cumbersome way of saying the same thing.